# Random variable with characteristic function $\large\frac{\phi(t)+\phi(-t)}{2}$

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Combinations of characteristic functions: $\alpha\phi_1+(1-\alpha)\phi_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178905/combinations-of-characteristic-functions-alpha-phi-11-alpha-phi-2)

If $\phi(t)$ is the characteristic function of a random variable $X$, then $\Re(\phi(t))$ is also a characteristic function of some random variable $Y$ (This can be easily seen by Polya's criterion). How can we find $Y$? ($\Re(\cdot)$ detones the real part of a complex number)

I have already read [**this**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178905/combinations-of-characteristic-functions-alpha-phi-11-alpha-phi-2?rq=1) related question but I cannot figure out the solution. How can we find the characteristic function of $AX+(1-A)(-X)$?

Comment: Think probabilistically about it. (Hint: Introduce an independent r.v. uniform on $\{-1,+1\}$.)

Comment: Isn't the characteristic function explicitly given in did's answer to question you link to?

Comment: Yes. My problem is how can we calculate $\mathbb{E}e^{it(AX+(1-A)(-X))}$, in order to show that the characteristic function is indeed $\Re(\phi(t))$.

Comment: Nick: Say, what prevented you to ask this on the other page?

Comment: I thought that since the other question was answered and the OP was satisfied with the answer, it would be better to ask a new question linking back to the other. Should I have asked my question in the comments of the old answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A$ be independent of $X$ with $P(A=1)=P(A=0)=\frac{1}{2}$. Then
$$
E\left[e^{it\{AX+(1-A)(-X)\}}\right]=\frac{1}{2}E\left[e^{itX}\right]+\frac{1}{2}E\left[e^{it(-X)}\right]=\frac{\phi(t)+\phi(-t)}{2},
$$
but using that $\cos$ is even and $\sin$ is odd, we obtain
$$
\phi(-t)=E\left[e^{i(-t)X}\right]=E[\cos(-tX)]+iE[\sin(-tX)]=E[\cos(tX)]-iE[\sin(tX)]
$$
and so $\phi(t)+\phi(-t)=2E[\cos(tX)]=2\Re(\phi(t))$, which yields the result.

Comment: So, we have that:  
$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{it\{AX+(1-A(-X)}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{it\{AX+(1-A(-X)\}}\cdot I_B\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[e^{it\{AX+(1-A(-X)}\cdot I_{B^c}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{itX}\cdot I_B\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[e^{it(-X)}\cdot I_{B^c}\right]=\mathbb{P}(B)\mathbb{E}\left[e^{itX}\right]+ \mathbb{P} (B^c)\mathbb{E}\left[e^{it(-X)}\right]$  
  
where $B=\{\omega: A(\omega)=1\}$. Right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Here we use the independence of $A$ and $X$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Is there an fast way to see $\mathbb{E}\left[e^{itX}\cdot I_B\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[e^{it(-X)}\cdot I_{B^c}\right]=\mathbb{P}(B)\mathbb{E}\left[e^{itX}\right]+ \mathbb{P} (B^c)\mathbb{E}\left[e^{it(-X)}\right]$? What theorem is used that gives us independence of the indicator and the composed function here, given the independence of A and X?

Comment: @GEO: We use the fact that if $X$ and $A$ are independent, then so is $f(X)$ and $g(A)$ for all measurable functions $f$ and $g$.